# How to convert a JSON array into a JSON object in JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

How do I convert a JSON array into a JSON object. For example, I have created a variable which holds a JSON array:

```
[{  "Bank Account Name": "State Bank",
    "Currency Code": "4000",
    "Deposit Date": "5/2/1794",
    "Payment Channel": "check"}]
```

How do I convert it into a JSON object with entities as a JSON object which look like this:

```
{"Entities ":[{  "Bank Account Name": "State Bank",
        "Currency Code": "4000",
        "Deposit Date": "5/2/1794",
        "Payment Channel": "check"}]
}
```

Is there a way to do this? I tried `Stringify` and `parse`.

Comment: When you say what you tried, please post some code. That way we can show you exactly why your code isn't doing what you want it to. Even better, you can create a fiddle, so we can test your code.

Comment: please provide your code when posting a problem

Comment: Is this really a question ?
`var newObj = {Entities: oldObj}`

Comment: Search and try this one `getJSONObject(int index)`

Comment: i see no json. [JSON](http://json.org/) is a string, representing a serialized object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var array = [{  "Bank Account Name": "State Bank",
    "Currency Code": "4000",
    "Deposit Date": "5/2/1794",
    "Payment Channel": "check"}];

var obj = {"Entities" : array};

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var original  = [{  "Bank Account Name": "State Bank",
"Currency Code": "4000",
"Deposit Date": "5/2/1794",
"Payment Channel": "check"}];

var newValue = JSON.stringify({Entities:[original[0]]});

console.log(newValue);
//{"Entities":[{"Bank Account Name":"State Bank","Currency Code":"4000","Deposit Date":"5/2/1794","Payment Channel":"check"}]}
```

Comment: Why `[original[0]]` ?

Comment: You're right, var newValue = JSON.stringify({Entities:original}); would work just as well :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var obj = [{  "Bank Account Name": "State Bank",
    "Currency Code": "4000",
    "Deposit Date": "5/2/1794",
    "Payment Channel": "check"}];
var objNew={};
objNew.Entitys=obj;

alert(JSON.stringify(objNew))
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap it:

```
var array = [{  "Bank Account Name": "State Bank",
    "Currency Code": "4000",
    "Deposit Date": "5/2/1794",
    "Payment Channel": "check"}];

var jsonObject = {"Entities":array};
```